# Changes to the function ajax-cart.js not showing in prestashop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, prestashop

I have made some changes to the function themes/default-bootstrap/js/modules/blockcart/ajax-cart.js.

```
    $(document).off('click', '#add_to_cart button').on('click', '#add_to_cart button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('product-id:'+$('#product_page_product_id').val()); //added this line
        console.log('quantity-wanted:'+$('#quantity_wanted').val()); //and this line
        ajaxCart.add($('#product_page_product_id').val(), $('#idCombination').val(), true, null, $('#quantity_wanted').val(), null);
    });
```

but when I upload it to the server and check the script in the browser I still see the old script.
I have refreshed the ftp, cleared the prestashop cache and browser cache.
Why is the browser not showing the updated function?

Comment: see  if the file is uploaded, may be you have not the right permission to upload

Comment: the file is uploaded, and viewing the uploaded file, shows changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the folder "cache/smarty" and the file "cache/class_index.php" just in case.

You say that you cleared the cache but do not indicate exactly how. Deleting those files clears the cache for sure, and if the file is in the server but doesn't get used by Prestashop it could be a cache issue.

Furthermore, that script is also in another place appart from the theme folder:

./modules/blockcart/ajax-cart.js

Try changing the script there also.

If it still doesn't work check that you do not have an external module installed that is replacing the core blockcart module. May be it helps if you search where all the instances of that js file using the command (assuming that you have command line access to the server):

sudo find . -name "ajax-cart.js"

It might help also knowing from where that java file is called with the command:

sudo grep -r --include=*.php "ajax-cart.js"

I have had similar issues and I solved them as explained. I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

clear browser cache (ctl + f5)

Comment: The OP has already stated in the question they have cleared the browser cache.